# CS:GO cvar command only works intermittently and Infinite Armor

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I'm very new to CS:GO. I currently have a problem with the `cvar` command. I often play offline with bots (casual). When I'm in game, pressing <kbd>~</kbd> to open the `cvar` command is fine. However, after a few seconds, it MAY not work anymore (pressing <kbd>~</kbd> doesn't show anything), but if it can "survive" the first few seconds, it will work as long as I do not quit the game. If the `cvar` command doesn't work, I have to exit CS:GO, re-launch it, and hope it may or may not work this time.

The only commands I use are: `sv_cheats "1"`, `mp_backup_round_file_pattern ""`, `mp_limitteams "0"`, `mp_autoteambalance "0"`, `mp_maxrounds "999"`, `mp_timelimit "0"`, `bot_add`, `bot_zombie "1"`. **Even if** I don't use those commands, it may not work either. Even though the problem doesn't always happen (40% of the time), it bothers me enough. What should I do? What's wrong with CS:GO?

I tried to re-install CS:GO, but the problem is still there.

Is there any way to have infinite armor (Kevlar and helmet)?

Comment: Have you tried binding console (as it is more commonly referred to), to another key or several other keys? I have it bound to ~ and /, because I switch between keysets and some keys are invalid / become invalid as I play. It is very weird, but if one key doesn't work the other one does. To bind console simply type "bind key console" into the console itself or in your .cfg / autoexec.cfg

Comment: You can check if a key is bound to anything by using console and type: "Bind [Key]" without anything after the [Key] part. If you want to rebind, do "unbind [key]", then "bind [key] {Command}" to bind it to whatever you want. Ignore the [] and {} of course. The reason you want to use unbind first is to make sure you don't bind multiple commands to the same key. An example of what I use is "bind F1 consoletoggle", so my F1 key acts as the open\close console screen key.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is your question: Is there any way to have infinite armor (Kevlar and helmet)? Then no. Depending on what you want to achieve, commands you might want to look into are:

Gives free armor to you and the bots (a map command): `mp_free_armor 1`

Gives you free kevlar and helmet: `give weapon_vesthelm`

Makes regeneration very rapid/makes you invulnerable: `sv_regeneration_force_on 1`

Answer (score 0):

I got into this problem, and it has nothing to do with the bind key. To prevent the intermittently working, only open cvar command after the word "MATCH START" disappears.

For free armor, I can only do that in older CS like CS Source with the help of Cheat Engine (freezing the value in the memory). It doesn't work in CS:GO because they probably initialize memory addresses after each match.